# Javascript TypeError : variable undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo el siguiente problema en mi código de `javacript`, he buscado todo tipo de soluciones y nada.

Aquí tengo mi código ready y funcionando versión prueba
`ajax.html` ahí todo

```
var arreglo;
    var area = new Array();
    var sigla = new Array();

function realizaProceso(){       

    $.ajax({
            data:  {},
            url:   'http://bioredsky.epizy.com/conexion.php',
            type:  'post',
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#status").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    arreglo = $.parseJSON(response);
            }
    });
}

    var con=0;
while(con<=arreglo.length-1){
     area[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("El area es: " + area[con]);
     con++;

     sigla[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("La sigla es: " +sigla[con]);
     con++;
     }
```

mi código anterior de prueba que esta en `ajax.html` lo copio en mi proyecto en `get_turn.js` donde tengo todas las funciones de `javascript`

```
    var arreglo;
    var area = new Array();
    var sigla = new Array();

function realizaProceso(){       

    $.ajax({
            data:  {},
            url:   'http://bioredsky.epizy.com/conexion.php',
            type:  'post',
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#status").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    arreglo = $.parseJSON(response);
            }
    });
}

    var con=0;
while(con<=arreglo.length-1){
     area[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("El area es: " + area[con]);
     con++;

     sigla[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("La sigla es: " +sigla[con]);
     con++;
     }
```

Y me aparece este siguiente error al inspeccionar el código:

> TypeError: arreglo is undefined

PostData :

1-el código que esta en ajax.html funciona correctamente.
2-Las librerias tambien funcionan correctamente.
3-la url :http.Bioredsky..... envia un arreglo hacia la funcion creada en ajax con json_encode.
4- He inicializado Arreglo como un New Arrays, le asiganado valor por defecto y nada.
5-Url: bioredsky..... no es la que estoy usando actualmente, las subi con ese ejemplo porque no estoy en mi pc.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Leandro, te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que sepas como formular preguntas que sean bien recibidas en la comunidad y obtengas las mejores respuestas de los usuarios, es importante que el código lo subas como tal (texto) y no como imágenes, saludos !

Comment: Muchas gracias Camilo lo tendre en cuenta para la siguiente pregunta.

Comment: Te aconsejo que des click en [edit] y la adecues para que no entre en votación por cierre, además te invito a que hagas el [tour] para que entiendas como funcionamos, saludos!

Comment: tienes que declarar `arreglo` como una variable osea `var arreglo = []`

Comment: Camilo gracias, Luis aun me sigue dando el mismo error

Answer (score 2):

El problema por el cual te esta sucediendo esto es porque estas intentando recorrer el arreglo sin tener en cuenta que ese arreglo depende de la llamada a tu servidor, la que se hace de forma asincronica. El `while` donde haces dicho proceso debe ir justamente despues de que escribes `arreglo = $.parseJSON(response)` que es cuando realmente arreglo porta informacion. Saludos.

Comment: En mi primer codigo de prueba todo funciona bien, primero haga la llamada al servidor para llenar el arreglo y luego es que recorros los arreglos con el while, y aun asi le asigno valor por defecto a la variable arreglo y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: @LeandroInc: En que linea te da el error??

Comment: TypeError: arreglo is undefined

Comment: @LeandroInc: No me refiero a eso. Cuando el navegador te da un error, te dice tambien a la derecha, la linea en la que ocurrio el error.

Comment: no dice linea, solo el error que te dije anteriormente y el archivo donde se encuenta

Comment: @LeandroInc: Que raro. Generalmente te ponen luego del nombre del archivo, la linea y la columna donde se encuentra el error...

Answer (score 0):

Las peticiones ajax tienen una comunicación [asincrónica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunicaci%C3%B3n_asincr%C3%B3nica) lo que quiere decir que cuando haces la petición no sabes exactamente el tiempo en dara una respuesta.

Por eso cuando haces la consulta y llenas el `arreglo` el puede durar mas tiemplo que en el que javascript procesa la función siguiente y no encuentra datos dentro del `arreglo`.

> Ejemplo con el código fuera de la respuesta del ajax. (Da Error porque no encuentra datos dentro de la variable `arreglo`)

```js
    var arreglo;
    var area = new Array();
    var sigla = new Array();

function realizaProceso(){   
$.ajax({
  url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  arreglo = data
});
}
realizaProceso()
    var con=0;
while(con<=arreglo.length-1){
     area[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("El area es: " + area[con]);
     con++;

     sigla[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("La sigla es: " +sigla[con]);
     con++;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Ejemplo donde ponemos la function dentro del `success` o en este caso el `then()` que seria lo mismo solo que es una [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).
>
> Nota: el ejemplo solo es para notar que no da error porque los datos dentro de la variable arreglo si son encontrados pero solo son de prueba y no contempla los mismos datos a procesar.

```js
var arreglo;
    var area = new Array();
    var sigla = new Array();

function realizaProceso(){   
$.ajax({
  url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  arreglo = data
      var con=0;
while(con<=arreglo.length-1){
     area[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("El area es: " + area[con]);
     con++;

     sigla[con]= arreglo[con];        
     alert("La sigla es: " +sigla[con]);
     con++;
     }
});
}
realizaProceso()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```